# Use purrr just like for-loop to append elements to a vector

Tags: r, loops, purrr

I have a problem with the functions of purrr.
I want to download several pdfs with walk2 and if a pdf cannot be downloaded a vector should be created with the problematic links. My code is the following:

```
missed <- c()

walk2(
  pdflinks,
  destfiles,
  ~ {
    Try <- try(
      download.file(.x, .y, mode = "wb")
    )

    if(class(Try) == "try-error"){
      print(.x)
      missed <- c(missed, .x)
    } 
  }
)
```

The vector missed filled should be appended with the problematic links just the same as if I would use a for-loop instead of purrr-function. I added a nonexisting link and the name is printed but the vector missed is still null after I run the script. Am I doing something wrong or can't this be done with a purrr-function?

Comment: Try `missed <<- ...`

Comment: Super, this works, thank you very much! Could you explain why only this works here but in a for-loop "<-" is enough?

Comment: If we assign in the normal manner to a variable in a function then a *copy* of the variable local to the function is made and the assignment is made to the copy.  On the other hand the body of a for loop is not a local environment.

Comment: @TonySunshine . You might be interested in the functions `safely()` and `possibly()`  for this task